# Disk Error on a Dell Notebook with Windows 8.1 “The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, has a bad block.”

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, chkdsk

Recently my computer freezes for minutes and after reboot I see in the Event Viewer many Errors such as "The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, has a bad block."

I have run chkdsk c:/R/B and chkdsk c:/offlinescanandfix

But no problems were detected!

How can I find and mark those bad blocks?

Detailed Error Message:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="disk" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49156">7</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-06-02T15:16:10.243994500Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>60791</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>Dell-W8</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>\Device\Harddisk0\DR0</Data> 
   <Binary>030080000100000000000000070004C0000100009C0000C0000000000000000000F0593A2D0000004F50000000000000FFFFFFFF010000005800008402000000F5200AFF42072040000200003C00000000000000000000001090713000E0FFFF00000000000000007022693300E0FFFF0000000000000000F82C9D16000000002800169D2CF800010000000000000000700003000000000000000000110000000000000000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: Please include the output of GSmartControl in your question.

Comment: Check the disk health using the official diagnostic tool provided by the manufacturer.

Comment: post pictures of this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html